# Has anyone tried to seek asylum in Lithuania on the train from mainland Russia to Kaliningrad?

Tags: russia, refugees, belarus, lithuania, kaliningrad

There are trains that transit from Russia to its enclave Kaliningrad and those trains now do not make stops in Lithuania.
However I wonder if there will be a chance to ask for asylum inside the train in Lithuania? I couldn't find any info on that.

Comment: If the train does not stop in Lithuania, how are you planning to get off it?

Comment: Unless Lithuanian border guards are on/enter the train at some point (possibly as part of customs checks on the transport of sanctioned goods) and you somehow get an opportunity to approach them, I’m not sure how this would be possible.

Comment: Even if the trains do not have any scheduled stops in Lithuania, they do stop. I was in Kybartai a few weeks ago, in Lithuania directly at the border to Kaliningrad, and a Russian train heading for Kaliningrad was standing at the station at a fenced off platform obviously waiting for a signal to proceed. Directly after the station, the tracks cross a busy road and then there is less than 200m to the actual border. I assume that the train doors are locked, preventing people from leaving the train while in transit.

Comment: I would also assume that there are Russian immigration officers or police on board all trains and that attempts to leave the train will likely be detected, prevented and lead to prosecution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suited to a legal forum

Comment: Will see maybe someone will try this and write a report

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo just pulling the alarm signal should be enough to stop the train and unlock the doors. At least it would be on most trains. On some trains the doors are actually not locked, and on others still there are manual opening procedures for doors. Of course many of those actions will cause disruption and are prosecutable offenses…

Comment: @jcaron If you with "alarm signal" mean the emergency break, it may for what I know be disabled while the train is in transit through Lithuania. I must admit that I have no specific knowledge about the Russian corridor trains through Lithuania, but I would assume that they are dispatched at least similarly to how West German trains were handled when on route to and from West Berlin through East Germany. There may be a whole lot of different deviations from regular train traffic.